# Unicity of the copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in an ordered field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

One can prove that every ordered field contains a copy of the ordered field $\mathbb{Q}$.

To show this, one can first show that every ordered field $K$ must be of characteristic $0$, and use this fact to show that the function  $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to K$ determined by $\phi(1):=1_K$ is an ordered ring monomorphism. Then, one can show that the function $\psi:\mathbb{Q}\to K$ defined by $\psi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right):=\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}$ is an ordered field monomorphism. In fact, this copy $\psi(\mathbb{Q})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ (which has the structure of an ordered field with the order relation inherited from $K$).

> **Question:** Is the following argument correct to show that $\psi(\mathbb{Q})$ is the only copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ ?

The ordered ring monomorphism $\phi$ must be such that $\phi(1):=1_K$, and since this condition determines $\phi$ completely, it is the only ordered ring monomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $K$. Also, if $\psi:\mathbb{Q}\to K$ is an ordered field monomorphism, then
\begin{align*}
\psi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)&=\psi(ab^{-1})\\
&=\psi(a)\psi(b^{-1})\\
&=\psi(a)\psi(b)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{\psi(a)}{\psi(b)}
\end{align*}
must be true, and since the restriction of $\psi$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ordered ring monomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $K$, it must correspond to $\phi$ by the unicity of such an identification. Hence,
$$
\psi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)}
$$
must be true. All in all, we see that we had only one choice in defining $\psi$, so that $\psi$ is the unique ordered field monomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $K$ and $\psi(\mathbb{Q})$ is the only copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also appeal to [the universal property of the field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions#Construction) which says that an injective homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ into a field uniquely determines an extension to $\Bbb Q$.

Since any other copy of $\Bbb Q$ in $K$ would have to share the same identity, it's clear that the two maps would have to match on $\Bbb Z$, and then they are forced to match on all of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, in fact the $\psi$ I defined in my question would be the explicit extension to the field of fractions. So my argument was correct?

Comment: @Amateur I suppose in this case that suffices, but appealing to the properties makes it a little more compact.